# EMI Filter compatible to both IEEE 802.3at and MIL-461F standards

Tags: emc, emi-filtering, poe

I'm designing an EMI filter for a PoE DC-DC converter. It's a typical filter:

[image]

However, IEEE 802.3at standard requires input bypass capacitor (from VDD to VSS) of 0.05 μF to 0.12 μF only.

Per my calculations for MIL-461F compliance, I need more than 0.12uF capacitor which is 0.4uF minimum.

I tried looking but I couldn't find any reference or guides on designing EMI filters for PoE and for MIL-spec compliance.

What should I do?